# How to mock methods that call other methods with no return value

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am very new to Mockito. I want to write a mock for the below method. How would I write it? What would my mock method look like?

```
public boolean validatePersonForBenefitsProcessing(PersonDTO person) {
        boolean continueProcessing = false;
        if (person.isPersonOnLeave()) {
            if (person.isBenefitsCoverage()) {
                if (person.isPersonDriver()) {
                    continueProcessing = true;
                } else {
                    if(person.isPersonOnSTD()) {
                        continueProcessing = false;
                    } else {
                        continueProcessing = true;
                        person.setSendPersonToInternal(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return continueProcessing;
    }
```

Comment: You said you're wanting to mock *this method*? Just return "true" or "false" as needed for your test case. If you're wanting to make sure that you're calling the setter, then you pass in the person with the property false and make sure that it's true at the end, no mocking required. By the way, a method that _both_ returns a value _and_ modifies its incoming parameter is unusual and likely to be surprising to other developers (a bad thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is what is your purpose for doing that?

If you want to test this method (for example: to improve coverage),
you could create a mock of the `PersonDTO` and define the behaviour it should exhibit by declaring the results of the method calls.

A example could look like this:

```java
public void test() {
    PersonDTO personMock = mock(PersonDTO.class);

    when(personMock.isPersonOnLeave()).thenReturn(true);
    when(personMock.isBenefitsCoverage()).thenReturn(true);
    when(personMock.isPersonOnSTD()).thenReturn(false);

    Assert.assertTrue(validatePersonForBenefitsProcessing(personMock));

    ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Boolean.class);
    verify(personMock).setSendPersonToInternal(captor.capture());

    Assert.assertTrue(captor.getValue());
}
```

However if you can just easily create `PersonDTO` object yourself and supply the necessary values,
its recommeneded to do just that. Mocking should generally be used for 'complex' objects that you can not simply create yourself.

---

If your purpose is to mock the method itself,
then assuming your Class would be `SomeClass` it could look like this:

```java
SomeClass mock = mock(SomeClass.class);
when(mock.validatePersonForBenefitsProcessing(any(PersonDTO.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

However as your class modifies both the incoming value, and the return value that would not be appropriate, as the modification of the incoming object would not happen.

You would be forced to do something like this instead:

```java
SomeClass mock = mock(SomeClass.class);
when(mock.validatePersonForBenefitsProcessing(any(PersonDTO.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

        PersonDTO dto = (PersonDTO) invocation.getArgument(0);
        dto.setSendPersonToInternal(true);

        return true;
    }
});
```

As `@chrylis` already commented, behaviour like this might suprise other developers and therefore should be avoided if possible. Also it makes testing much easier ;)

Also as `@chrylis` said there is nothing in this method that would really require you to do this kind of mocking, as you can freely control the path the code takes by manipulating the input parameter.